# What could cause Facebook to remove all my app testers from the roles section?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Any reason why facebook would remove/kill my testers?

The testers disappeared under the app roles section in my developer account section (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayz7V.png)

I had 6 testers and now it's saying 'There are no testers for this app'

my app mode wan't live but I've adding testers for last 2-3 years.  In last two weeks I added two ( last night I added one) and now they've all disappeared.

thanks in advance

I tried looking in other forums but couldn't find anyone experiencing similar issue.

Comment: did you every find an answer to this? got the same problem and dont know why